# While getting the productCollection trough $block->getLoadedProductCollection(), no access on custom attributes - why?

Tags: magento2, phtml

The Problem:
I am modifying the `Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml` and I'm trying to access my custom attribute `ku_untetitel`.

In the .phtml, I'm using the following code to get the productCollection (magento default):

```
$_productCollection = $block->getLoadedProductCollection();
```

And I try this to get my custom attribute:

```
<span class="description">
    <?php
            if(!empty($_product->getData('ku_untertitel'))):
            echo $_product->getData('ku_untertitel');
        endif;  
    ?>
</span>
```

When taking a look at the frontend, the HTML is there, but the content is empty, like this:

```
<span class="description">



</span>
```

What am I doing wrong here, and why can't I access custom attributes when getting the product Collection trough something else then my own Collection? I suppose the collection doesn't contain much more information then the basic attributes, but not the custom attributes.

How can I modify my files in order to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, make sure our custom attribute can be used in product listing:
**STORES > Product Attributes >** select your custom attribute **> Storefront Properties > Used in Product Listing** to **Yes**

[image]

Second, assign our attribute to Attribute Set: **STORES > Product Attributes > Attribute Sets**

Third, if we take a look at `vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list.phtml`, we can see the way how to  get product attribute value, e.g: `$_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name')`. So, we can get our custom attribute like:

```
$_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getKuUntertitel(), 'ku_untertitel');
```

Clear Magento Cache and refresh the product listing page.

Comment: Can you edit your last code to match my attributes name? I doubt that I can call it with $_product->getku_untertitel()...

Comment: Updated my code `$_product->getKuUntertitel()`

Answer (score 0):

You can just add in code as below,
 `$_productCollection->addAttributeToSelect('your_attribute')`;